# Como puedo ver paso a paso un metodo con Debug

Tags: java

Se que tengo que ir a la modalidad Debug, pero no se como imponer un breakpoint dentro del codigo para ver paso a paso como interactuan las variables y el metodo mismo

Comment: ¿Qué entorno de desarrollo estás usando? ¿IntelliJ IDEA, Netbeans, Eclipse, Visual J++/J#, otro diferente?

Answer (score 1):

Para añadir un BreakPoint basa con ir a la clase donde quieras ponerlo y y hacer doble click en el margen izquierdo del editor, en la línea donde quieres que se pare la ejecución.

[image: BreakPoint]

Y estos son algunos de los atajos de teclado para avanzar la ejecución:

- Resume(F8); continúa con la ejecución (hasta el próximo breakpoint).
- Step Into (F5); se detiene en la primer línea del código del método que estamos ejecutando. Si no hay método, hace lo mismo que Step Over.
- Step Over (F6); pasa a la siguiente línea que vemos en la vista de código.
- Step Return (F7); vuelve a la línea siguiente del método que llamó al método que se está depurando actualmente.

Comment: Te faltó detallar que para empezar el debug hay que dar al "bichito verde" de la parte de arriba del entorno. Saludos!

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217/342)